# C# DbContext.Add strange behaviour

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have this following piece of code:

```
class Email_DAO{
   static Database database = null;
   public static void uploadToDb(EmailTrovate e)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.email+"\n\n");
                if (database == null) database = new Database();
                database.Emails.Add(e);
                database.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException); }
        }
        public static void uploadListToDb(List<EmailTrovate> listEmail)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach(EmailTrovate email in listEmail)
                {
                    uploadToDb(email);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) {}
        }
}
```

And a snapshot of the database before the execution: (the PK is made up of both ID and email)

```
+----+---------------+
| ID |     email     |
+----+---------------+
| 01 | test@test.com |
+--------------------+
```

now, from another part of the code (e.g. Main) if I write

```
EmailTrovate x1 = new EmailTrovate();
EmailTrovate x2 = new EmailTrovate();
x1.ID = 01;
x1.email = test@test.com;
x2.ID = 02;
x2.email = anothermail@provider.com;
List<EmailTrovate> list = List<EmailTrovate>();
list.Add(x1);
list.Add(x2);
Email_Dao.uploadListToDb(list);
```

**Expected behaviour:**

```
test@test.com
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_email_trovate'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EmailTrovate'. The duplicate key value is (test@test.com, 1).

anothermail@provider.com;
OK
```

**Actual behaviour:**

```
test@test.com
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_email_trovate'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EmailTrovate'. The duplicate key value is (test@test.com, 1).

anothermail@provider.com;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_email_trovate'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.EmailTrovate'. The duplicate key value is (test@test.com, 1).
```

Basically it does not allow me to insert the second entry! And the exception says "The duplicate key value is (test@test.com, 1)" for both of them when they clearly are two different objects. In the method I even printed the mail which is printed correclty, so why does it try to add the first ogject again? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Start with, don't cache a DbContext...

Comment: @TheGeneral I'm sorry, what do you mean? What could I do?

Comment: A new instance per transaction

Comment: @Jasen yeah, seems to work! Why does that happen? Furthermore the List might be very long, a new instance per transaction couldn't be overhead?

Comment: It's how it was designed to be used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/

Comment: I think there is a misconception on the behaviour of save changes. While you think that on failure all tracked changes are discarded, but this is not the case. So when you add the second email. The first email is still listed as an item to track, and it will just try to save again. As @Jasen explained the context is a unit of work. Also, if you would add all items first and save at the end it will be faster (but measuring is key)